# Who assigns the hotness points to certain Hot questions and on what basis are they awarded?

Tags: support, questions, stackexchange

Recently i have found that all the [Hot questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) are assigned particular numbers which are called the "hotness points".

When we hover mouse over a particular question, we get to know how much point it has been awarded with.

For example, for [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104858/can-i-refuse-to-choose-seats-with-additional-cost-at-check-in-time) it's said:

> This question has been arbitrarily awarded 78,451 hotness points.

I am curious to know who awards these points only on some particular questions and on what basis are these points awarded?

Although it says "arbitrarily awarded" still there has to be some principle behind the act of assigning particular numbers to particular questions.

For example, how to decide exactly how many "hotness points" should be awarded to a particular Hot question?

Comment: Refer [How do the “arbitrary hotness points” work on the new Stack Exchange home page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60756)

Comment: When you have a general question like this which is applicable to all the sites, you can also post it on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @NogShine, the issue with main meta is that the users there are mostly non forgiving. If they happen to don't like the Qn or even if they feel that the user hasn't done enough research about duplicates, then they downvote the Qn without showing any mercy. These downvotes will haunt even if we delete our own Qn. Based on certain downvotes to a Qn, a user account is blocked from asking Qn for several weeks. Own experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From following post:
[How do the "arbitrary hotness points" work on the new Stack Exchange home page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60756/163449)

```
(MIN(AnswerCount, 10) * QScore) / 5 + AnswerScore
-------------------------------------------------
         MAX(QAgeInHours + 1, 6) ^ 1.4
```